# How to convert this respond_to options to use Rails 3 version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, respond-to, respond-with

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.js { render :nothing => true, :status => :ok, :location => @user }
  else
    format.js { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

All options I've tried (like putting `respond_to :js` at the top of controller, etc) don't quite work the way as in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3 Format:

Use **respond_to** :json and **respond_with**(@user)

```
  respond_to :json  # You can also add  , :html, :xml  etc.

  def create
    @user= User.new(params[:user])
      #---For html flash
      #if @user.save
      #  flash[:notice] = "Successfully created user."
      #end
    respond_with(@user)
  end

# Also, add :remote => :true, :format => :json to the form.
```

Comment: Is it a security risk to return the entire object model (since the user could see all the data using firebug console)? -- I ask because most models would have boolean fields that you'd store also -- and might not be best to show the user.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `format.json` instead of `format.js` in your controller and `:remote => :true, :format => :json` in corresponding form.

Though, I'm not quite sure whether `format.json` or `format.js` should be used in that case. As default scaffolding from Rails 3 generates controllers with `format.json` and you're doing `render :json` in response I believe `format.json` is the right way to go. And `format.js` should be used when you return a piece of JS that should be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The URL your are requesting should end with `.json` like this: `/controller/action.json`

If that is not possible:

You should set the `'accepts'` parameter to `'application/json'` while sending the ajax request.

Search for how to use `'accepts'` here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And in the server side:

```
format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
```