# Return json at create new row at database in Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

Hi everyone i am making an app with a backend in rails, i need to create a user from an ajax request and the server have to return a json object with the new user saved.

This is my code of rails

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

   def nuevo_usuario
      @u = User.new(params[:user])
      @u.save       
      respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render :json => @u }
      end
    end

end
```

And this is the code of javascript

```
$.post("http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/nuevo_usuario.json", $("#resgistro-form").serialize(), function(data){});
```

And the server respond with this

```
Started POST "/users/nuevo_usuario.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-14 10:17:22 -0500
Processing by UsersController#nuevo_usuario as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"user"=>"prueba", "mail"=>"prueba@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (72.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "mail", "password", "updated_at", "user") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 14 Jun 2013 15:17:22    UTC +00:00], ["mail", "prueba@gmail.com"], ["password", "preuba"], ["updated_at", Fri, 14 Jun 2013 15:17:22 UTC +00:00], ["user", "prueba"]]
   (18.2ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 395ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 310.0ms)
```

I don't receive the json object that i send with rails.

if you need more information just tell me, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at only the log file? That won't include the actual response body.

Comment: I look for the response body with firebug and is empty, i start to think that is something about the crossdomain ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Add "respond_to :json"

So that it is something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
       respond_to :json

   def nuevo_usuario
      @u = User.new(params[:user])
      @u.save       
      respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render :json => @u.as_json }
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: i add respond_to :json before the nuevo_usuario method and didn't work, i also try with removing respond_to code block and replace it with respond_with function that i found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200929/how-to-convert-this-respond-to-options-to-use-rails-3-version but dont work :(

Comment: sorry, I saw I made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I upload my code to heroku and complied the app with phongap and it works fine, i think that the problem was crossdomain and crossbrowser ajax request